# Can I uninstall eclipse plugins from eclipse's osgi console?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp, equinox

I have uninstalled some plugins/bundles from osgi console (from inside eclipse), but when I restart eclipse they are running again. is there any way to make eclipse uninstall those plugins from osgi console ?? I know they will be gone if I remove them from /plugins folder, but thats not what I want.

If its not possible can I somehow use osgi to remove those plugins ?

Comment: Non-console, but Help > About eclipse > Installation Details > Installed Software has an Uninstall... button.

Comment: This would be really helpful for me as well. Maybe some removal scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse uses it's own provisioning system on top of OSGi that manages plugin installs and maintains OSGi configuration state - p2. So whatever you do in OSGi console will be lost after restart unless you tell p2 to change it's state.
Luckily p2 has it's own commands available in console, they're documented in http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Console_Users_Guide

Please see example there.